# JTSage DatePicker - formatting options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

Is there a list anywhere of the date tags that the excellent [JTSage DatePicker for JQuery Mobile](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) will accept in the overrideDateFormat option? (ie.I wanted to show Wed, 01 January 2012 for example - but not sure of the %Y %m tags) - thank you for any pointers.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this in the calendars forums: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/dateformat.html

Mark